# Comparing two measures on trees on $n$ vertices

Tags: pr.probability, random-graphs, co.combinatorics

A standard measure on trees on $n$ vertices is the Uniform Spanning Tree (UST) on the complete graph.  This is the measure where every tree has equal probability, $1 / n^{n-2}$ by Cayley's formula.

Here is another measure.  Take an Erdős–Rényi (i.e. edge independent) random graph $G \in G(n,p)$ with $p$ large enough to ensure that $G$ is asymptotically almost surely connected, and then choose a UST on $G$.

Note that if $p = 1$ these two measures are identical.  My guess is that they are close (say in total variation distance), even for much smaller $p$.  In particular,  suppose that $$p \ge \frac{\log n + \omega}{n},$$ where $\omega \to \infty$ arbitrarily slowly as $n \to \infty$.  (This is barely sufficient to guarantee that the probability that $G$ is connected tends to one.)

> Are these actually the same measure in
>   disguise?  If not, can we say that
>   they are "close" to the same measure,
>   for example, by putting an upper bound
>   on the total variation distance
>   between the two measures that tends to
>   zero as $n \to \infty$?

Answer (score 6):

It's a nice question that I don't know a complete answer to.  However it can be seen that the measures are not exactly the same.  Take $p$ to be very small.  The most likely connected $G$ is a tree, and all trees are equally likely.  The next most likely $G$ is a unicyclic graph, whose numbers of spanning trees vary. Calculating $K_{1,3}$ versus $P_4$ shows that $K_{1,3}$ is a little bit more likely.

The exact expression for the probability of a given $T$ is a polynomial in $p$, so if this polynomial is not constant for tiny $p$ it won't be constant for larger $p$ either.

It would be very interesting to know how much the distributions can differ in general.

Answer (score 4):

It's a nice question. The following is not an answer but too long to put in comment. I think in general you want to ask "how much can you tell of the underlying graph given a sample from the uniform spanning tree". There is a great algorithm due to David Wilson to sample the UST, which consists in growing the tree by successively running loop-erased random walks. See eg http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop-erased_random_walk.

Here I think you can try to generate the graph at the same time as the loop-erased random walks, which means that for a while you can couple a loop-erased random walk on the complete graph with one on $G(n,p)$. Not sure this method will allow you to go all the way to the connectivity threshsold $p = (1+ \epsilon) \log n / n$, though. Perhaps it would be easier to start with $p=1/2$ !